# Type mismatch when getting header info using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, type-mismatch

I am using the following to code to pull test header information from an LMS Waterfall:

```
Dim usr_attr As LMSTestLabAutomation.AttributeMap
Dim num_usr_att As Integer
Dim user_data_array() As String
Dim user_label_array() As String

Set usr_attr = my_db.GetProperties("")
num_usr_att = usr_attr.Count
ReDim user_label_array(num_usr_att - 1)
ReDim user_data_array(num_usr_att - 1)

I = 0
For I = 0 To num_usr_att - 1
   user_label_array(I) = usr_attr.KeyNames.Item(I)
   user_data_array(I) = usr_attr.Item(I)
Next I

'Enter the data into the report
wb.Sheets("Multi-cut Report").Select ' Switch to the Report Page
Set mcwb = wb.ActiveSheet

wb.ActiveSheet.Range("C5") = user_data_array(Application.Match("UA::Test request number:", user_label_array, False) - 1)
wb.ActiveSheet.Range("C6") = user_data_array(Application.Match("UA::Test Start Date", user_label_array, False) - 1)
wb.ActiveSheet.Range("C7") = user_data_array(Application.Match("UA::Test By", user_label_array, False) - 1)
wb.ActiveSheet.Range("C8") = user_data_array(Application.Match("UA::Test Location", user_label_array, False) - 1)  '<<<< function fails here <<<<
```

The last line of code gives me a type mismatch. However, prior to making my changes to the code (which did not include this block of code), I would not get a type mismatch and it would return the value in the header. When this bit of code is commented out, the script runs exactly as expected otherwise.

Comment: Before anything else, you need to rethink your use of `num_usr_att`. If `usr_attr.Count = 0` you will get error trying to ReDim with a negative number. Also try in Immediate window: `?Application.Match("UA::Test Location", user_label_array, False)` see if it gives `0`, if so, none is found and so you are trying to access an array with negative index - fails for sure.

Comment: Thanks PatricK for pointing out the Immediate Window, didn't know that feature existed! Due to this I found my answer, I needed to use a wildcard in the string literal "UA::Test Location*" to get the correct result. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code runs when the string in the faulty line of code uses a wildcard:

```
wb.ActiveSheet.Range("C8") = user_data_array(Application.Match("UA::Test Location*", user_label_array, False) - 1)
```

I believe that at some point the header file had been appended with a non-printing character, hence why a direct match would not work. Thanks to PatricK for his advice.